# How to traverse shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, void-pointers

Can someone help me to finish this?

I have a `vector` of `int`. How to get back this `vector<int>` or traverse it in the `foo()` function?

```
std::vector<int> myIntVec = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
auto mBlock = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(myIntVec);
std::shared_ptr<void> in = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(mBlock);
foo(in);

void foo(std::shared_ptr<void> input) {
        
    //TODO:: print 1, 2, 3, 4 extract from std::shared_ptr<void> input parameter
    
    auto sp_vec = std::static_pointer_cast<std::vector<int>>(input);
    auto vec = sp_vec.get();
        
}
```

Comment: `const char* sep = ""; for (auto e : *vec) { std::cout << sep << e; sep = ", "; }`?

Comment: `sp_vec` is a pointer(-like) to the vector. So just use `*sp_vec` where you would otherwise use the vector directly in the iteration...